# Ladder climbing function in C# script for Unity won't allow the character to come off the ladder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a function in Unity that is supposed to allow the character to climb. It creates two problems, first of all it somehow interacts with the general movement function. When the character starts running their animation won't stop even when the player isn't moving them. Second of all the character can climb up and down the ladder but won't get off them, even though technically the logic is constructed in such a way that they should just go back to their normal state.

I have tried turning off the climb function in the Update() function so I know the running problem is caused by it, because it works fine without it.

```
private void Climb()
    {
        RaycastHit2D ladder = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.up, 5, whatIsLadder);

        float hDirection = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vDirection = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if (ladder.collider != null)
        {
            if (vDirection > 0.1f)
            {
                isClimbing = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (hDirection > 0.1f)
            {
                isClimbing = false;
            }        
        }

        if (isClimbing == true && ladder.collider != null)
        {

            rb.gravityScale = 0;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, climbSpeed * vDirection);
            if (Mathf.Abs(vDirection) > 0.1f)
            {
                anim.speed = 1f;
            }
            else
            {
                anim.speed = 0f;
            }

        }
        else
        {
                rb.gravityScale = naturalGravity;
        }

    }
```

I'll also give a link to the whole PlayerController script since that might help some people:
https://github.com/Pacal2/Platformer/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resetting the velocity on the rigidbody when he stops climbing, near the end of the function:

```
//....
{
rb.gravityScale = naturalGravity;
}
```

into:

```
{
rb.gravityScale = naturalGravity;
rb.velocity = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

this code also looks suspect

```
    if (ladder.collider != null)
    {
        if (vDirection > 0.1f)
        {
            isClimbing = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (hDirection > 0.1f)
        {
            isClimbing = false;
        }        
    }
```

change to:

```
    if (ladder.collider != null)
    {
        if (vDirection > 0.1f || vDirection < -0.1f) //if allowed to climb down
        {
            isClimbing = true;
        }

        if (hDirection > 0.1f || hDirection < -0.1f) //moving left
        {
            isClimbing = false;
        }        
    }
```

for animation speed try:

```
anim.speed = rb.velocity.x;
```

Comment: You might be on to something but that still didn't change the fact that the character is constantly running (animation-wise) also I just realized that the character will move horizontally on the ladder even "outside of it" to the sides. It doesn't cause them to fall off, they' can move however much they want to the left and right and are constantly in their climb state.

Comment: i expanded my answer let me know if ithelps

Comment: Sadly, I already picked on that one but correcting it didn't help. I'll add this though. As I mentioned my character can move to the left/right outside of the ladder. But when I do that I can't move up and down. They can only move up when they are on the actual ladder. So it definitely recognizes when the player's and ladder's colliders interact.

Comment: Did some  rewriting  and it seems to work fine. Istead of raycasting I just used a simpler method to see if colliders are touching. I still have problem with one thing. The method is supposed to also change the animation speed depending on the players input. So they don't just look like they're moving on the ladder when they aren't. But they are moving all the time anyways. Here's the code:
           
            if (Mathf.Abs(vDirection) > 0.5f)
            {
                anim.speed = 1f;
            } else
            {
                anim.speed = 0f;
            }
        
`

Comment: try anim.speed = Mathf.abs(vDirection);

Comment: i added something else to try to my answer

Comment: glad to hear, if this worked mark it as correct and upvote